# After a job interview, is it inappropriate if I want to talk to an employee in private?

Tags: interviewing, new-job, recruitment

I would possibly ask if they are happy about working for the company and maybe a few more questions about the corporate culture.

Comment: This seems perfectly fine to do *during* the interview when they ask if you have any questions for them. Is there a specific reason you think it should be done after the interview?

Comment: @RhysW I just dont have a preference, my main purpose is to talk to an employee.

Comment: Is there any reason you dont want to do this during the interview? I'm struggling to see why this needs to be done after an interview in private when that is exactly the kind of thing the interview is for! Finding out if you want to work there. I'm just trying to see if there is a question here worth asking, the current one is likely to be closed off as not a real question if you have no reason to not do it in the interview!

Comment: I don't doubt that this would be a valuable thing to do, but I can't see a potential employer allowing you to do this. Perhaps after a 2nd/3rd interview (if they were happy with you) this might be permitted. Also understand that one person's opinion is highly subjective - even if you were to hand-pick someone doing a similar role to that you were being interviewed for.

Comment: I would think finding someone on LinkedIn or otherwise outside the official interview structure (former employees probably would be even better). It sounds like you want to get a really personal, honest perspective on the company rather than the "marketing image" you get during interviewing?

Answer (score 14):

It is not considered to be inappropriate at all and in some interviews this has been part of the interview process. Here are some helpful hints during your interview staying both positive and on track.

- **If you could describe your corporate culture in three words, what
  would you say?**

  This question accomplishes several goals. First, it's creative. That
  positions you as a thinker, not just another resume. Second, it
  challenges the interviewer to boil down the essence of their
  workplace in only a few words. Finally, your interviewer's response
  isn't as important as how she responds. Watch her body language.
  Check her posture. And keep an eye on her facial expressions. Look
  for consistency between actions and words to get the true description
  of the culture. Because someone's body never lies to you.
- **If you were going to give public tours of this company, what stops
  would the guide make?**

  This is another creative question to challenge your interviewer.
  What's more, her answers will represent the "greatest hits" of the
  company's culture. This delivers invaluable insight into what they
  perceive as the leading attributes of their company. After all, you
  wouldn't make it a stop on the tour if it didn't symbolize a core
  component to the company's culture, right?
- **If the local paper were going to run a four-page article about your
  company's culture, what would be impossible not to include?**

  Creative, challenging and counterintuitive. Also positions you in a
  positive light, regardless of the answer. And, similar to the tour
  question, this allows your interviewer to put her company in the best
  light. The secret is, by suggesting a newspaper article it reveals
  the parts of the company's culture that she would want the public to
  know about. Transparency is key.
- **What's the best part about working in this environment that I won't
  be able to see from just a walk around the office?**

  This question digs deep into the true value of working in a
  particular company environment. You learn the culture behind the
  culture, as some workplaces are quite different once you've been
  employed there for a few months. This might be helpful in eliciting a
  little candor in your interviewer about the reality you'd be working
  in. Sometimes culture is hard to discern from a brief walkthrough or
  few weeks of work.
- **What are the most common complaints employees make about your company
  culture?**

  Although you want to keep your interview as positive as possible,
  throwing a monkey wrench into the interview gears might not be a bad
  idea. Especially because it's an unexpected question. The cool part
  is, by discovering the negative aspects about a company before
  working there, you know what to expect. Like visiting Portland during
  wet season (September through May) before deciding to move there. At
  least there's no sugar coating.
- **May I speak with a few of your veteran employees or new hires?**

  Some companies will already schedule this experience into the
  interview process. On the other hand, some companies will not allow
  you to contact existing employees. Either way, asking such a question
  — and, if you're lucky, getting an affirmative answer — will provide
  the best insight into corporate culture, as it comes from a team
  member himself. If you can make it happen, you'll be glad you asked.
  Because behavior is the broadcaster of attitude, and attitude is the
  reflection of culture.
- **What do you love best about the culture here?**

  Finally, try getting personal. Find out what brings your interviewer
  back to work every day. Find out what prevents her from leaving the
  company and going somewhere else. This example is your best tool as a
  "final" question to ask toward the end of the interview. Just be sure
  not to ask it too early. Wait until you've created a connection and
  built rapport with the interviewer. That way you'll be guaranteed an
  authentic answer

Remember: Company culture is everything. You can't work where you don't fit.

Ask a few of these questions on your next interview, and you'll be sure to find the organization that's the right environment for you.

Comment: Hi, whilst this is an indepth answer the only part that attemtps to answer the actual question is the first sentence. The rest of this answer seems to be addressing a question that wasn't asked ("What questions should i ask in an interview")

Comment: @RhysW The OP is asking for questions for the company culture which was the last part of his question. In my response I have included questions, speaking to previous employees as well as how to find out if they would be happy working for the company.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps you are correct, my mistake

Comment: By using a few of these questions as pointed out in my last sentence you can gain a great insight into what the company is like. Thank you for pointing that out though.

Comment: FYI, I have been approving your edits painfully - it's grammar, not grammer :)  (this comment will likely self destruct...)

Comment: I don't blame you for feeling the pain....I'm starting to now fml :L...thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's fine - they may already do it.  When you get into a serious battery of interviews, check the list of people to see if a peer is included.  If not, ask the interview coordinator if it's possible to spare someone's time when you come in - say you'd really like a peer's perspective on the work and the company.

I like @Michael Grubey's potential question list.  You'll probably want to pick and choose - often a single answer can lead off a great discussion better than any formal list.  One thing to be aware of is that whether it's private or not, an employee is unlikely to say "this place is awful... don't come!".  Misery loves company, and bad mouthing your employer - no matter how private - is a bad idea.  So "are you happy?" may get you a hard to read response, where something more tangential may be more enlightening.

Most productive is to focus on opportunities, important aspects of culture, and the personal qualities that the company most values - that lets the employee speak positively while still painting a picture about aspects of the company you want to be aware of.

Comment: Absolutely - raises a good point that if it's possible to do it in person, go for that - it's much easier to read body language than the implication of pauses on a phone line.